# htaccess rewritecond rewriterule http https

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

I have a website on apache with ssl. I want to redirect the users to the https version but also I need to be able to open the 'http' version when I need it.
For example:

```
example.com --> has to be redirected to 'https://www.example.com'
www.example.com --> has to be redirected to 'https://www.example.com'
http://example.com --> has to open 'http://example.com' without redirect
```

I'm trying with this but can't reach the goal:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http:\\example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http:\\example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
----------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http\:\\$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried a few more syntaxes..

Comment: `example.com` and `http://example.com` are the same URL since browsers default to HTTP. (Although they "did", an issue now is that browsers are starting to default to HTTPS - so what you are suggesting may not be possible going forward.) You could perhaps try `example.com` on HTTP (or rather, no redirect) and `www.example.com` on HTTPS? But you need to be careful with canonicalisation. Might I suggest an alternative... you could append a query string, eg. `noredirect=1` to prevent a redirect. (This could also set a cookie if you need this is persist between requests?)

Comment: Can I ask "why" you need to be able to access HTTP? This is an unusual request these days.

Comment: Because the website is a personal uploader running on a small hardware and I want to give safe access to others and keep access on http for me if I need faster transferring. The throughput in http is much better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's nice information. Actually, when I go to 'example.com' it opens <code> https://example.com </code> and when I go to 'www.example.com' it opens <code> http://example.com </code> . Then will it be possible to simulate a subdomain? for example redirecting all trafic to the https except if I request 'fast.example.com' , in that case go to the 'http' ?? could it work?